# WCF Cannot create channel factory with given endpoint name

Tags: c#, wcf

I would like to create a channel factory for my self-hosted service. Here is my App.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="mexBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="mexBehavior" name="Service.TexasHoldemService">
        <endpoint address="TexasHoldem" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
            contract="Service.ITexasHoldemService" name="TexasHoldem"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080" />
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8090" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Here is how I host the service

```
host = new ServiceHost(typeof (Service.TexasHoldemService));
host.Open()

var factory = new ChannelFactory<ITexasHoldemService>("TexasHoldem");
```

However, I am getting a an exception like this:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll

Could not find endpoint element with name 'TexasHoldem' and contract 'Service.ITexasHoldemService'
in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was
found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this name could be
found in the client element.
```

I also tried with setting address in ChannelFactory constructor as:

```
http://localhost/TexasHoldem
http://localhost/Service.TexasHoldemService/TexasHoldem
net.tcp://localhost/TexasHoldem
net.tcp://localhost/Service.TexasHoldemService/TexasHoldem
```

And none of the above works ;/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an `<endpoint>` under a `<client>` element to be able to call it from `ChannelFactory`:

Add the following code under `<system.serviceModel>`:

```
  <client>
    <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8090/TexasHoldem" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="Service.ITexasHoldemService" name="TexasHoldem">
    </endpoint>
  </client>
```

Comment: I did as you advised and when i create factory with "net.tcp://localhost:8090/TexasHoldem" i get the same error :( When I created the factory with "TexasHoldem" string as a endpoint address, I got an exception that the URI must be absolute.

Comment: The piece of code in the config which is responsible for hosting must have address="net.tcp://localhost:8090/TexasHoldem" and the client end point should point to the same address as well.This is not a valid address for a WCF service - address="TexasHoldem"